# How to show data from controller in ajax function success

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

i try to show data in html page from controller with ajax function,when i try to alert data at function success but it show json data and current page html tags. I not able to show data in table view. please help me.
below show the code:

```
$(".statuss").on("click",'', function(){
  var ele=$(this).closest('tr');
    var id=document.querySelector('.statuss:checked').value;
   var site=document.getElementById('sites').value;
   //alert(id);
  // alert(site);
  var isGood = confirm('Are you Sure??'); 
  if (isGood) {
      $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "<?php echo site_url("dashboard/get_keyword");?>",
            data: {
              id:id,
              site:site,
            },
           // dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                //console.log(data);
            $("#table_result").removeClass("hidden");
            $("#table_result_list").removeClass("hidden");
            $("#table_result_footer").removeClass("hidden");
            $("#table_inputs_head").removeClass("hidden");

            alert(data);
            //for {
                var d = $.parseJSON(data);
            //}
            alert(d);    
                var output;
                $.each(d,function(i,e) {
          // here you structured the code depend on the table of yours
           output += '<tr><td>'+e.keyword+'</td><td>'+e.id+'</td></tr>';
          // alert(e.keyword);
            });

          //  alert(datas);
            $("#table_result_list").html(data);
          //   $("#table_result_list").append(output);

            // alert(data);

            }
        });
    } 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

change header in your controller like this..

```
header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');
$result= // your code.......
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

In your controller print the table in controller itself or create a view file to print tables,

in your ajax function

```
success: function(data) {

 $("#table_result_list").html(data);
}
```

Comment: Now it work, i wrote table html code in controller  and at function success append this data to particular div id

Comment: Thank you for your reply